# How do I update my react dependencies after upgrading to react v16?

Tags: reactjs, dependencies

After upgrading to react v16, other dependencies are showing warnings when I use yarn:

```
warning "react-chartjs-2@2.1.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14 || ^15.0.0-rc || ^15.0".
warning "react-chartjs-2@2.1.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^0.14 || ^15.0.0-rc || ^15.0".
warning "react-motion@0.5.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14.9 || ^15.3.0".
warning "react-router@3.0.5" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0".
warning "react-router-dom@4.1.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^15".
warning "react-router@4.1.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^15".
warning "react-scrollchor@4.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "fbjs@*".
warning "react-sizes@0.1.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^15.6.1".
warning "react-sizes@0.1.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^15.6.1".
warning "react-addons-test-utils@15.6.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^15.4.2".
```

How do I update these components? Do I have to manually use yarn to add the latest version for each one? Will that fix this? BTW, these warnings apparently have no effect on my app, it still compiles and runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run the command `yarn upgrade` in your terminal
https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/upgrade/

Comment: This will update all your packages.  If you want to install only specific modules, use the command `yarn upgrade {package name}`

Comment: I did each one separately, specifying the latest version: e.g.

Comment: I did each one separately, specifying the latest version: e.g. yarn upgrade react-motion@^0.5,2. Only using the package name without the version number did not upgrade to the latest. This took a few minutes, but I wanted to test each change as I did them.

Comment: I understand you wanted to test them, but if you want the latest version of all your dependencies you can add the `latest` paramater onto the `yarn upgrade` command.  So use `yarn upgrade latest` to upgrade all dependencies to their latest versions.  Otherwise they will only upgrade to the `wanted` version!

Answer (score 0):

You can install [npm-check-updates](https://github.com/tjunnone/npm-check-updates) and run `ncu -a` in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

[npm install -g npm-check-updates](http://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/update-npm-packages/) command will check and install it for you inside package.json